# rails test:case integration how to specify format

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing

I've this

```
post(my_path, params: {param: :one}, format: :js)
```

However I receive this error

```
ArgumentError: unknown keyword: format
```

What is the right way to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should provide fomat to path like this

```
my_path(format: :js)
```

Comment: Good upvotes come to those who wait, oh ye of little faith: the rewards do come.